# How could I do something like this in a XML schema?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to mass create some users and I want to set the users timezone automatically. However I am using timezones generated by this

```
 Dictionary<string, TimeZoneInfo> storeZoneName = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToDictionary(z => z.DisplayName);
```

So I need the names to be exactly like the ones this list returns. So can I put like a constraint on that xml node that the name has to exactly match one of the names.

So I am guessing I will need to write this list somewhere in the file and that's what I am not sure if you can do something like that in a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a predefined list of values you'll want to use **XSD Enumerations**.

See links below:

**[xml.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/02/05/wxs-enum.html)**

**[w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-enumeration)**

Comment: Cool what is the "id" for in XSD Enumerations? My timezone dictionary does have an "id" and a display name. Could I use the id field for the id of the timezone?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to link enumerations for two elements or attributes.  For example, if timezone 6 is 'US Central', I don't think you can force the XML to make sure that if the "timezone" element is 6 then the "Description" element must be "US Central".  You would probably have to merge the two fields, e.g put them in one tag like "6 - US Central"